# JQuery Calender default date when there is already a date in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

So I have a questions about calendars using JQuery in ASPNET. Currently, I have a textbox with a date that is being pulled from a SQL database. When the user clicks on the textbox a calendar pops up below the textbox and the user can select the new date. But as of right now, if there is a date in the textbox the calendar defaults to that date. For example if the date in the textbox is 02/28/1998, the calendar defaults to that date. I want to set it up so that when the user clicks on the textbox with a date, it defaults to todays date on the calendar and places it in the textbox also. How can I do this?

**ASP CODE:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAnnualReviewD" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IRBAnnualDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'CssClass="JDateTextbox" />
```

**SCRIPT CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.JDateTextbox').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-10:+5"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a .datepicker option called showButtonPanel that adds a Today button to the calendar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.JDateTextbox').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            yearRange: "-10:+5"
        });
    });
</script>
```

See example:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#buttonbar

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I will be bookmarking the link you also provided.

Comment: No problem, it has a lot of great examples with other widgets your likely to come across too.